# In triangle $\triangle ABC$, angle $\angle B$ is equal to $60^\circ$; bisectors $AD$ and $CE$ intersect at point $O$. Prove that $OD=OE$.

Tags: geometry, triangles, plane-geometry, angle

In triangle $\triangle ABC$, angle $\angle B$ is equal to $60^{\circ}$; bisectors $AD$ and $CE$ intersect at point $O$. Prove that $OD=OE$.

So I've already made a diagram(it is attached below), but I don't know how to prove it from there. Please help and explain your solution thoroughly because I have a test about this tomorrow and I want to understand this! Thank you! :D

[image]

Comment: Hint: Prove that $BDOE$ is a cyclic quadrilateral and use that $BO$ bissects $\angle EBD$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the angle in $A$ $2\alpha$, then the angle in $C$ is $120-2\alpha$ and $OCA=60-\alpha$. So $DOE=COA=180-(\alpha +60-\alpha)=120$ so the $ODBE$ is cyclic. Now observe that $BO$ must be the bisector of $B$ and so $OED=OBD=30$ and also $ODE=OBE=30$. Since $OE$ and $OD$ are oblique sides of a isosceles triangle they must be equal.

Comment: thank you so much for the great solution! but do you mean $DOE=COA$ in the second line?

Comment: Yes, sure @pleasehelpme

Answer (score 0):

Note that O is the incenter of Triangle ABC.
Thus, perpendiculars from O to sides AB and BC have equal length. Let them be G and H respectively. Can you prove that $\triangle$ OGE and $\triangle$ OHD are congruent?

Hint : Use the fact that $\angle$ AOC is $120^o$ and also the fact that $\angle$ GOH is also $120^o$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$\begin{aligned}\angle DOE &= \angle AOC\\ &= 180^{\circ} - (\angle OAC + \angle OCA)\\ &= 180^{\circ} - \frac{1}{2} (\angle BAC + \angle BCA)\\ &= 180^{\circ} - \frac{1}{2} (180^{\circ} - \angle ABC)\\ &= 120^{\circ}.\end{aligned}$$
Hence, $\angle DOE + \angle BOE = 180^{\circ}$, so $BDOE$ is cyclic. Therefore, since $\angle ODE = \angle OBE = \angle OBD = \angle OED$, $OED$ is an isosceles triangle, so $OD = OE$.